# How To Debug A C# Class Library COM Interop Component

Tags: c#, debugging, com-interop

I have a C# class library which I also use via COM Interop. To test the library I added a C# test app to the solution, set it to the startup project and I can test it that way. The library works fine this way but one function is not working when called via COM Interop from a Visual C++ 6 test application. How do I debug the library in this situation? I searched for a solution on Google but the only advice I can find is to add a test app to the solution which of course I can't do in this situation.

EDIT: Very sorry. I forgot to say the Visual C++ test application is Visual C++ 6.

Comment: More information is required. You debug it by trying to figure out the reason your not getting the expected value, you do that by, debugging your own code before and after the COM method is called

Comment: That was exactly the question. How to debug? Sorry I think you misunderstand the issue.

Comment: Why on earth are you using such an ancient C++ compiler?  This is the problem of course, VS6 doesn't know anything about C# debugging.  Fix the problem by adding a C++ project to your Solution so you can debug them both.

Comment: The reason am I using VC6 to create a test app is because I have an old VC6 application that needs to use this component. Howewver, it is easier to work with a simple test app to try and work out why it isn't working. I have already debugged the component with a VS2010 test app. That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, open boot Visual Studio and Visual C++. Start your test application in VC++. After that, in VS, open the Debug menu and choose the Attach to process. This will show you a list of current process that are running, choose the one corresponding to your test application and click on Attach. This will enabled you to put breakpoint and debug your DLL.

Comment: I had already tried this and it didn't work. It attaches to the process but all the breakpoints become greyed out.

Comment: Sorry I downvoted the answer but it is actually my fault for not explaining that the test app is Visual C++ 6 connecting to my C# library via COM Interop.

Comment: Are you using the Debug version of your DLL?

Comment: In the Project property windows, in the Debug tab, did you try it with the Enabled unmanage code debugging or unchecking the Enable the Visual Studio hosting process